# The downloaded code from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi does not build properly. Error for Nuget pckgs

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, owin, nuget-package

I downloaded solution code from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi.
But when I try to rebuild it, I am getting errr for Owin NuGet package. ['Owin.1.0.1' is not found]
I am sure that path for nuget packages are proper in my settings.

Any suggestions?

I added paths for NuGet sources. Also
I copied Owin 1.0 NuGet package from other solution to this downloaded solution, as well as in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages but it still does not wor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to Owin 1.0.1 appears to be an error because [the most recent version of the Owin NuGet package is 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin).

Another user has raised a GitHub issue [Nuget package Owin.1.0.1 can not be found #160](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/issues/160) reporting that they were able to fix this by manually editing the .csproj and .config files.

> #### Issue
>
> After cloining the repo, and rebuild with restore packages, i got an error that package Owin version="1.0.1" can not be found.
>
> #### Solution
>
> I had to manually remove all the references to this package (package.config and .csproj files), then reinstall the missing Owing package with the only available version of 1.0.0

Give this a try and let us know if it fixes the issue for you.